# Sort complex JSON object by specific property

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, sorting

How can I sort the given JSON object with property `count`. I want to sort the entire sub-object. The higher the count value should come on the top an so on.

```
  {
    "Resource": [
      {
        "details": [
          {
            "value": "3.70"
          },
          {
            "value": "3.09"
          }
        ],
        "work": {
          "count": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "details": [
          {
            "value": "4"
          },
          {
            "value": "5"
          }
        ],
        "work": {
          "count": 2
        },
        {
        "details": [
          {
            "value": "5"
          },
          {
            "value": "5"
          }
        ],
        "work": "null"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this example to sort your data:

```
data = {
    "data": {
        "Resource": [
            {
                "details": [{"value": "3.70"}, {"value": "3.09"}],
                "work": {"count": 1},
            },
            {"details": [{"value": "4"}, {"value": "5"}], "work": {"count": 2}},
        ]
    }
}

# sort by 'work'/'count'
data["data"]["Resource"] = sorted(
    data["data"]["Resource"], key=lambda r: r["work"]["count"]
)

# sort by 'details'/'value'
for r in data["data"]["Resource"]:
    r["details"] = sorted(r["details"], key=lambda k: float(k["value"]))


# pretty print:
import json

print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```json
{
    "data": {
        "Resource": [
            {
                "details": [
                    {
                        "value": "3.09"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "3.70"
                    }
                ],
                "work": {
                    "count": 1
                }
            },
            {
                "details": [
                    {
                        "value": "4"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "5"
                    }
                ],
                "work": {
                    "count": 2
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```